# Does $N \subseteq M$ implies $L^N \subseteq L^M$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $N \subseteq M$ be two transitive models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Let $L^N$ and $L^M$ denote the constructible universes in $N$ and $M$ respectively. Is it true that $L^N \subseteq L^M$?

I believe that this is true, which can be proven using Gödel's operations to represent $\operatorname{Def}(L_\alpha)$ for each level $L_\alpha$, but perhaps a much simpler argument works. I also believe that, by the same logic, $L[A]^N \subseteq L[A]^M$ and $L(A)^N \subseteq L(A)^M$ for $A \in N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can see this in several different aspects, especially in the case of transitive models.

$L^M$ is also a transitive model, and therefore equals to $L_\alpha$, where $\alpha=M\cap\rm Ord$. So, if $M\subseteq N$, then for some $\alpha,\beta$, $L^M=L_\alpha$ and $L^N=L_\beta$, and by the inclusion, $\alpha\leq\beta$, so the answer becomes very apparent.

But you can also notice that the definition of $L$ is *very* simple. Indeed, $\alpha\mapsto L_\alpha$ is a $\Delta_1$ function, so it is absolute between transitive models of set theory, in particular, for any $\alpha\in M$, $L_\alpha^M=L_\alpha^N$, and so $L^M\subseteq L^N$.